# uniformly continuous function maps bounded sets to bounded sets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I would appreciate if you gave my proof a look over, i'm getting a bit stuck towards the end. thank you very much. first time writing in latex by the way, so apologies beforehand.

claim: let $f: M \to N$ be a uniformly continuous function. Show that $f$ maps bounded sets to bounded sets.

proof: If $ m \subset M$ is bounded, then $ d(p,q) < B $ for fixed p and all q $ \in $ m.

let $F (m) $ be the image of m.

by definition of uniform continuity,

For all $ \epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all p,q such that $d(p,q) < \delta $  $\implies $ $d(f(p),f(q)) < \epsilon$

edit: cannot let $\delta = m$

so now i'm thinking that if we hold p and vary q, we will cover M with a set of open balls. Because M is bounded, that means this set of open balls is finite. and we can use that to similarly bound $f(m)$ with a finite set of open balls by the continuity definition.

*** this strategy would be assuming the set were "totally bounded", meaning it can be covered by a finite number of open balls of any radius. thanks for pointing out the term, user251257

edit: it's two general metric spaces, we cannot assume it's R.

Comment: what is $M$? ${}$

Comment: You can't say "let $B=\delta$": $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: M and N are metric spaces.

Comment: thank you spinoza. i thought that was might be wrong

Comment: are you sure that the claim is bounded set maps to bounded set? I am not sure if it is correct. However, **totally bounded** set maps to totally bounded set.

Comment: f maps bounded sets to bounded sets. and we have defined bounded sets  as I did in the proof (same as rudin)

Comment: It is wrong. Consider the identity function from the integers endowed with the discrete metric to the integers endowed with the usual Euclidean metric.

Comment: well the discrete metric would ensure that the set of integers is bounded.

but would this be a uniformly continuous function? I was thinking that it wouldn't because a bound on the distances in M would not provide a bound on the distances in N.

Comment: @mac5 the identity is uniformly continuous. The crucial point is, that there are only integers. Just check the definition.

Comment: Just take $\delta = 1/2$ in the case of the discrete metric.

Comment: which definition should i check? the one for uniform continuity?

Comment: @mac5 eh yes. Because you asked whether the identity is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

In general this is not true for arbitrary metric spaces but if $M=N=\mathbb R$ with the standard metric, you can argue as follows:

$f$ is uniformly continuous on $m\subseteq M$, so it extends to a (uniformly) continuous function on $\overline m$, which is also bounded, hence compact. Of course, $f(m)\subseteq f(\overline m)$, and the latter is compact hence bounded,so that $f(m)$ is bounded as well.